# Why am I getting WCF error?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

Am getting this error when I browse to a .svc page in IIS
[ie. **http://localhost/PTSNew/PTNewService.svc**].Could you please advise on how to resolve this error?And also, is the url given in baseAddress attribute incorrect?Thanks.

*

> Service 'PTSNew.PriceTestingService' has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no service element
>   matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or
>   because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

*

Heres my interface and app.config xml:

```
namespace PTSNew 
{ 
    // NOTE: If you change the class name "Service1" here, you must also update the reference to "Service1" in App.config.

        public class PriceTestingService : IPriceTesting, IDisposable
}

namespace PTSNew 
{ 
    // NOTE: If you change the interface name "IService1" here, you must also update the reference to "IService1" in App.config.

    [ServiceContract] 
    public interface IPriceTesting 
}

<system.serviceModel> 
    <bindings> 
      <basicHttpBinding> 
        <binding name="ProviderBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" 
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"> 
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" 
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" /> 
          <security mode="Transport"> 
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" /> 
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" /> 
          </security> 
        </binding> 
      </basicHttpBinding> 
      </bindings> 
    <services> 
      <service name="PTSNew.PriceTestingService" behaviorConfiguration="PTSNew.Service1Behavior"> 
        <host> 
          <baseAddresses> 
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/PTSNew/PriceTestingService/" /> 
          </baseAddresses> 
        </host> 
        <!-- Service Endpoints --> 
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above --> 
        <endpoint address ="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="PTSNew.IPriceTesting"> 
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically. 
          --> 
          <identity> 
            <dns value="localhost"/> 
          </identity> 
        </endpoint> 
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints --> 
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment --> 
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/> 
      </service> 
    </services> 
    <behaviors> 
      <serviceBehaviors> 
        <behavior name="PTSNew.Service1Behavior"> 
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment --> 
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/> 
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information --> 
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" /> 
        </behavior> 
      </serviceBehaviors> 
    </behaviors> 
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems that you have forgotten to write **contract** attribute for the **service** element

please go to the http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/first_WCF_Service.aspx to see an example

Comment: Thanks oleksa.I believe I have the required node with contract attribute in the xml already as shown in the question:--><endpoint address ="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="PTSNew.IPriceTesting">

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place your configuration in web.config file instead of app.config if you are hosting it on IIS.

And baseAddress is ignored when you are hosting WCF serwise on IIS. Base address is determined by web site and web application address where your WCF service is placed.

Comment: Thanks Marek.Sure I will try this.And if this does work, then the error message that am getting is quite a misleading one![or just one of the many misleading ones in WCF area].

Answer (score 0):

Your service contract (`IPriceTesting`) doesn't expose any methods. You need to add methods to the interface and decorate them with the `OperationContract` attribute. After that, you need to implement those methods in your service class (`PriceTestingService`).

Example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPriceTesting
{
    [OperationContract]
    decimal GetPrice(int productId);
}
```

And

```
public class PriceTestingService : IPriceTesting
{
    public decimal GetPrice(int productId)
    {
        //TODO: implement the method body
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Rick, I skipped the implementation logic/other details here for brevity.I do have all these things added in my code already.Thanks.